petl evaluation sequence possibly causing grief
In Python's petl library, according to the documentation, "This package makes extensive use of lazy evaluation and iterators. This means, generally, that a pipeline will not actually be executed until data is requested." ETL Pipelines
I've tried to handle that in the following code:

`import petl as etl
import re

# Functions to be used for conversions
def convert_commissioning_year(year):
    match year:
        case None:
            return 0
        case "NA":
            return 0
        case str.find("s"):
            # If the year is a string with an s at the end, we assume it indicates decade (like 2970s)
            middle_year = int(str(year)[:-1]) + 5
            return middle_year
        case _:
            return int(year)

# Clean 'max_speed_warp_factor' by extracting the numeric portion
def extract_numeric_speed(speed):
    print("JOLL")
    if isinstance(speed, str):
        match = re.search(r"[\d]+[.][\d]", speed)
        if match:
            return float(match.group())
    return None

# Load the CSV data using petl
table = etl.fromcsv('/Documents/star_trek_table.csv')
# Standardizing column names to snake_case
table2 = etl.rename(table, {
    'Ship Name': 'Name',
    'Registry Number': 'RegNo',
    'Captain(s)': 'Captain',
    'Launch Date': 'Commissioning',
    'Notable Appearances (Series/Movies)': 'Appearances',
    'Ship’s Complement': 'Complement',
    'Max Speed (Warp Factor)': 'Warp'
})
# Convert 'launch_date' and 'ships_complement' to integers (handling any errors)
table3 = etl.convert(table2, 'Commissioning', convert_commissioning_year)
table4 = etl.convert(table3, 'Complement', int)
table5 = etl.convert(table4, 'Warp', extract_numeric_speed)
# Strip any leading/trailing whitespace in string columns
table6 = etl.convertall(table5, lambda v: str.strip(v))

# Display the cleaned data (in a limited format for brevity)
print(etl.lookall(table6))

# Save the cleaned data back to CSV
etl.tocsv(table6, '/Documents/cleaned_star_trek_table.csv')

print("END")


The printout:

`/petl/.venv/bin/python /petl/main.py 
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| Name                           | RegNo        | Class                 | Captain                              | Commissioning | Appearances                                           | Complement | Warp |
+================================+==============+=======================+======================================+===============+=======================================================+============+======+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701)'    | 'NCC-1701'   | 'Constitution-class'  | 'Capt. James T. Kirk, Capt. Pike'    | None          | 'Star Trek: TOS, Movies I-IV, VI'                     | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-A)'  | 'NCC-1701-A' | 'Constitution-class'  | 'Capt. James T. Kirk'                | None          | 'Star Trek IV-VI'                                     | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-B)'  | 'NCC-1701-B' | 'Excelsior-class'     | 'Capt. John Harriman'                | None          | 'Star Trek: Generations'                              | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-C)'  | 'NCC-1701-C' | 'Ambassador-class'    | 'Capt. Rachel Garrett'               | None          | 'Star Trek: TNG (Episode: "Yesterday\'s Enterprise")' | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D)'  | 'NCC-1701-D' | 'Galaxy-class'        | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              | None          | 'Star Trek: TNG, Movies VII, VIII'                    | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-E)'  | 'NCC-1701-E' | 'Sovereign-class'     | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              | None          | 'Movies VIII-X'                                       | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Voyager (NCC-74656)'      | 'NCC-74656'  | 'Intrepid-class'      | 'Capt. Kathryn Janeway'              | None          | 'Star Trek: Voyager'                                  | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Defiant (NX-74205)'       | 'NX-74205'   | 'Defiant-class'       | 'Capt. Benjamin Sisko'               | None          | 'Star Trek: Deep Space Nine'                          | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Discovery (NCC-1031)'     | 'NCC-1031'   | 'Crossfield-class'    | 'Capt. Gabriel Lorca, Capt. Pike'    | None          | 'Star Trek: Discovery'                                | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Cerritos (NCC-75567)'     | 'NCC-75567'  | 'California-class'    | 'Capt. Carol Freeman'                | None          | 'Star Trek: Lower Decks'                              | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Shenzhou (NCC-1227)'      | 'NCC-1227'   | 'Walker-class'        | 'Capt. Philippa Georgiou'            | None          | 'Star Trek: Discovery'                                | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Excelsior (NCC-2000)'     | 'NCC-2000'   | 'Excelsior-class'     | 'Capt. Hikaru Sulu'                  | None          | 'Star Trek VI, Star Trek III'                         | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Saratoga (NCC-31911)'     | 'NCC-31911'  | 'Miranda-class'       | 'Capt. J.G. Sanders'                 | None          | 'Star Trek IV, DS9 (pilot)'                           | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Prometheus (NX-59650)'    | 'NX-59650'   | 'Prometheus-class'    | 'Various (Multivector Assault Mode)' | None          | 'Star Trek: Voyager (Episode: "Message in a Bottle")' | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Thunderchild (NCC-63549)' | 'NCC-63549'  | 'Akira-class'         | 'NA'                                 | None          | 'Star Trek: First Contact'                            | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Yamato (NCC-71807)'       | 'NCC-71807'  | 'Galaxy-class'        | 'Capt. Donald Varley'                | None          | 'Star Trek: TNG'                                      | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Equinox (NCC-72381)'      | 'NCC-72381'  | 'Nova-class'          | 'Capt. Rudolph Ransom'               | None          | 'Star Trek: Voyager (Episode: "Equinox")'             | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Reliant (NCC-1864)'       | 'NCC-1864'   | 'Miranda-class'       | 'Capt. Clark Terrell'                | None          | 'Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan'                     | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Stargazer (NCC-2893)'     | 'NCC-2893'   | 'Constellation-class' | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              | None          | 'Star Trek: TNG (Episode: "The Battle")'              | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Titan (NCC-80102)'        | 'NCC-80102'  | 'Luna-class'          | 'Capt. William Riker'                | None          | 'Star Trek: Lower Decks, Star Trek: Picard'           | None       | None |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+

JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
JOLL
END

Process finished with exit code 0

Why is the function extract_numeric_speed being evaluated at the end, and why do I end up with None-values in all converted columns? Thanks.
I was expecting to get converted values in the respective columns.
I renamed the table to a sequence of tables (table1, table2, etc) take into account petl's lazy evaluation.
The original table looks like this:
    +--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| Ship Name                      | Registry Number | Class                 | Captain(s)                           | Launch Date | Notable Appearances (Series/Movies)                   | Ship’s Complement | Max Speed (Warp Factor)   |
+================================+=================+=======================+======================================+=============+=======================================================+===================+===========================+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701)'    | 'NCC-1701'      | 'Constitution-class'  | 'Capt. James T. Kirk, Capt. Pike'    | '2245'      | 'Star Trek: TOS, Movies I-IV, VI'                     | '430'             | 'Warp 8'                  |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-A)'  | 'NCC-1701-A'    | 'Constitution-class'  | 'Capt. James T. Kirk'                | '2286'      | 'Star Trek IV-VI'                                     | '500'             | 'Warp 9'                  |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-B)'  | 'NCC-1701-B'    | 'Excelsior-class'     | 'Capt. John Harriman'                | '2293'      | 'Star Trek: Generations'                              | '750'             | 'Warp 9.6'                |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-C)'  | 'NCC-1701-C'    | 'Ambassador-class'    | 'Capt. Rachel Garrett'               | '2344'      | 'Star Trek: TNG (Episode: "Yesterday\'s Enterprise")' | '700'             | 'Warp 9'                  |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D)'  | 'NCC-1701-D'    | 'Galaxy-class'        | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              | '2363'      | 'Star Trek: TNG, Movies VII, VIII'                    | '1014'            | 'Warp 9.6'                |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-E)'  | 'NCC-1701-E'    | 'Sovereign-class'     | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              | '2372'      | 'Movies VIII-X'                                       | '885'             | 'Warp 9.99'               |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Voyager (NCC-74656)'      | 'NCC-74656'     | 'Intrepid-class'      | 'Capt. Kathryn Janeway'              | '2371'      | 'Star Trek: Voyager'                                  | '150'             | 'Warp 9.975'              |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Defiant (NX-74205)'       | 'NX-74205'      | 'Defiant-class'       | 'Capt. Benjamin Sisko'               | '2370'      | 'Star Trek: Deep Space Nine'                          | '50'              | 'Warp 9.982'              |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Discovery (NCC-1031)'     | 'NCC-1031'      | 'Crossfield-class'    | 'Capt. Gabriel Lorca, Capt. Pike'    | '2256'      | 'Star Trek: Discovery'                                | '136'             | 'Warp 9.99 / Spore Drive' |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Cerritos (NCC-75567)'     | 'NCC-75567'     | 'California-class'    | 'Capt. Carol Freeman'                | 'NA'        | 'Star Trek: Lower Decks'                              | '80'              | 'Warp 7'                  |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Shenzhou (NCC-1227)'      | 'NCC-1227'      | 'Walker-class'        | 'Capt. Philippa Georgiou'            | '2256'      | 'Star Trek: Discovery'                                | '215'             | 'Warp 8'                  |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Excelsior (NCC-2000)'     | 'NCC-2000'      | 'Excelsior-class'     | 'Capt. Hikaru Sulu'                  | '2287'      | 'Star Trek VI, Star Trek III'                         | '750'             | 'Warp 9.5'                |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Saratoga (NCC-31911)'     | 'NCC-31911'     | 'Miranda-class'       | 'Capt. J.G. Sanders'                 | 'NA'        | 'Star Trek IV, DS9 (pilot)'                           | '36'              | 'Warp 8'                  |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Prometheus (NX-59650)'    | 'NX-59650'      | 'Prometheus-class'    | 'Various (Multivector Assault Mode)' | '2374'      | 'Star Trek: Voyager (Episode: "Message in a Bottle")' | '4'               | 'Warp 9.99'               |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Thunderchild (NCC-63549)' | 'NCC-63549'     | 'Akira-class'         | 'NA'                                 | 'NA'        | 'Star Trek: First Contact'                            | '500'             | 'Warp 9.8'                |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Yamato (NCC-71807)'       | 'NCC-71807'     | 'Galaxy-class'        | 'Capt. Donald Varley'                | 'NA'        | 'Star Trek: TNG'                                      | '1014'            | 'Warp 9.6'                |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Equinox (NCC-72381)'      | 'NCC-72381'     | 'Nova-class'          | 'Capt. Rudolph Ransom'               | '2370s'     | 'Star Trek: Voyager (Episode: "Equinox")'             | '80'              | 'Warp 8.6'                |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Reliant (NCC-1864)'       | 'NCC-1864'      | 'Miranda-class'       | 'Capt. Clark Terrell'                | '2285'      | 'Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan'                     | '281'             | 'Warp 8.5'                |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Stargazer (NCC-2893)'     | 'NCC-2893'      | 'Constellation-class' | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              | 'NA'        | 'Star Trek: TNG (Episode: "The Battle")'              | '500'             | 'Warp 9'                  |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 'USS Titan (NCC-80102)'        | 'NCC-80102'     | 'Luna-class'          | 'Capt. William Riker'                | 'NA'        | 'Star Trek: Lower Decks, Star Trek: Picard'           | '350'             | 'Warp 9.99'               |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+


Why are you trying to call str.strip on non-string values?

Thanks, @user2357112. It was a leftover from earlier. Completely missed it.

Thanks to the comment above, I was able to make a working solution. It looks like this:
import petl as etl
import re

# Functions to be used for conversions
def convert_commissioning_year(year):
    match year:
        case None:
            return 0
        case "NA":
            return 0
        case _:
            # If the year is a string with an s at the end, we assume it indicates decade (like 2970s)
            if year[-1] == "s":
                middle_year = int(str(year)[:-1]) + 5
                return middle_year
            else:
                return int(year)

# Clean 'max_speed_warp_factor' by extracting the numeric portion
def extract_numeric_speed(speed):
    if isinstance(speed, str):
        match_float = re.search(r"\s\d+[.]\d", speed)
        match_int = re.search(r"\s\d+", speed)
        if match_float:
            return float(match_float.group())
        else:
            return float(match_int.group())
    return None

# Load the CSV data using petl
table = etl.fromcsv('/home/eric/Documents/star_trek_table.csv')

# Simplifying column names
table2 = etl.rename(table, {
    'Ship Name': 'name',
    'Registry Number': 'reg_no',
    'Captain(s)': 'captain',
    'Launch Date': 'commissioning',
    'Notable Appearances (Series/Movies)': 'appearances',
    'Ship’s Complement': 'complement',
    'Max Speed (Warp Factor)': 'warp_speed'
})
# Convert 'launch_date' and 'ships_complement' to integers (handling any errors)
table3 = etl.convert(table2, 'commissioning', convert_commissioning_year)
table4 = etl.convert(table3, 'complement', int)
table5 = etl.convert(table4, 'warp_speed', extract_numeric_speed)

# Display the cleaned data (in a limited format for brevity)
print(etl.lookall(table5))

# Save the cleaned data back to CSV
etl.tocsv(table5, '/home/eric/Documents/cleaned_star_trek_table.csv')

This gives the output:
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| Name                           | RegNo        | Class                 | Captain                              | Commissioning | Appearances                                           | Complement | Warp |
+================================+==============+=======================+======================================+===============+=======================================================+============+======+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701)'    | 'NCC-1701'   | 'Constitution-class'  | 'Capt. James T. Kirk, Capt. Pike'    |          2245 | 'Star Trek: TOS, Movies I-IV, VI'                     |        430 |  8.0 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-A)'  | 'NCC-1701-A' | 'Constitution-class'  | 'Capt. James T. Kirk'                |          2286 | 'Star Trek IV-VI'                                     |        500 |  9.0 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-B)'  | 'NCC-1701-B' | 'Excelsior-class'     | 'Capt. John Harriman'                |          2293 | 'Star Trek: Generations'                              |        750 |  9.6 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-C)'  | 'NCC-1701-C' | 'Ambassador-class'    | 'Capt. Rachel Garrett'               |          2344 | 'Star Trek: TNG (Episode: "Yesterday\'s Enterprise")' |        700 |  9.0 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D)'  | 'NCC-1701-D' | 'Galaxy-class'        | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              |          2363 | 'Star Trek: TNG, Movies VII, VIII'                    |       1014 |  9.6 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-E)'  | 'NCC-1701-E' | 'Sovereign-class'     | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              |          2372 | 'Movies VIII-X'                                       |        885 |  9.9 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Voyager (NCC-74656)'      | 'NCC-74656'  | 'Intrepid-class'      | 'Capt. Kathryn Janeway'              |          2371 | 'Star Trek: Voyager'                                  |        150 |  9.9 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Defiant (NX-74205)'       | 'NX-74205'   | 'Defiant-class'       | 'Capt. Benjamin Sisko'               |          2370 | 'Star Trek: Deep Space Nine'                          |         50 |  9.9 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Discovery (NCC-1031)'     | 'NCC-1031'   | 'Crossfield-class'    | 'Capt. Gabriel Lorca, Capt. Pike'    |          2256 | 'Star Trek: Discovery'                                |        136 |  9.9 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Cerritos (NCC-75567)'     | 'NCC-75567'  | 'California-class'    | 'Capt. Carol Freeman'                |             0 | 'Star Trek: Lower Decks'                              |         80 |  7.0 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Shenzhou (NCC-1227)'      | 'NCC-1227'   | 'Walker-class'        | 'Capt. Philippa Georgiou'            |          2256 | 'Star Trek: Discovery'                                |        215 |  8.0 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Excelsior (NCC-2000)'     | 'NCC-2000'   | 'Excelsior-class'     | 'Capt. Hikaru Sulu'                  |          2287 | 'Star Trek VI, Star Trek III'                         |        750 |  9.5 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Saratoga (NCC-31911)'     | 'NCC-31911'  | 'Miranda-class'       | 'Capt. J.G. Sanders'                 |             0 | 'Star Trek IV, DS9 (pilot)'                           |         36 |  8.0 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Prometheus (NX-59650)'    | 'NX-59650'   | 'Prometheus-class'    | 'Various (Multivector Assault Mode)' |          2374 | 'Star Trek: Voyager (Episode: "Message in a Bottle")' |          4 |  9.9 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Thunderchild (NCC-63549)' | 'NCC-63549'  | 'Akira-class'         | 'NA'                                 |             0 | 'Star Trek: First Contact'                            |        500 |  9.8 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Yamato (NCC-71807)'       | 'NCC-71807'  | 'Galaxy-class'        | 'Capt. Donald Varley'                |             0 | 'Star Trek: TNG'                                      |       1014 |  9.6 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Equinox (NCC-72381)'      | 'NCC-72381'  | 'Nova-class'          | 'Capt. Rudolph Ransom'               |          2375 | 'Star Trek: Voyager (Episode: "Equinox")'             |         80 |  8.6 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Reliant (NCC-1864)'       | 'NCC-1864'   | 'Miranda-class'       | 'Capt. Clark Terrell'                |          2285 | 'Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan'                     |        281 |  8.5 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Stargazer (NCC-2893)'     | 'NCC-2893'   | 'Constellation-class' | 'Capt. Jean-Luc Picard'              |             0 | 'Star Trek: TNG (Episode: "The Battle")'              |        500 |  9.0 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+
| 'USS Titan (NCC-80102)'        | 'NCC-80102'  | 'Luna-class'          | 'Capt. William Riker'                |             0 | 'Star Trek: Lower Decks, Star Trek: Picard'           |        350 |  9.9 |
+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------+

